# After I buy player switch character doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a 2d game, and after I buy player, it doesn't let me stay in the menu to choose the map for the player (I made 3 maps). The game starts and is just the first player I created.

Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject avatar1, avatar2;
    int wichAvatarIsOn = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);            
    }

    public void SwitchAvatar()
    {
        switch (wichAvatarIsOn)
        {
            case 1:
                wichAvatarIsOn = 2;
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                wichAvatarIsOn =  1;
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the script for the purchase. What should I write at `BuyComplete`? Should I search for another script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PurchaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BuyComplete(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Scene/Room3");
    }

    public void BuyFailed(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product, UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchaseFailureReason fa)
    {
        Debug.Log("PURCHASE FAILED");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded `wichAvatarIsOn = 1` so it will always use the same avatar.

You need to store the just purchased avatar.

You can use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to store information between scenes and game loads.

Once you have it stored somewhere you need to then select it from you `Start()` method using the `SwitchAvatar()` method you already have.

**SwitchScript**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject avatar1, avatar2;
    int wichAvatarIsOn;
    void Start()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("wichAvatarIsOn"))
        {
            wichAvatarIsOn = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("wichAvatarIsOn");
        }
        else
        {
            wichAvatarIsOn = 1;//Default to an avatarID you want as default
        }
        SwitchAvatar(wichAvatarIsOn);
    }

    public void SwitchAvatar(int avatarID)
    {
        switch (avatarID)
        {
            case 1:
                wichAvatarIsOn = 2;
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                wichAvatarIsOn =  1;
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;
            default:
                //Set a default avatar incase out of range and add a debug message
                Debug.Log("Avatar ID out of range: " + avatarID);
                wichAvatarIsOn = 2;
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**PurchaseScript**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PurchaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BuyComplete(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("wichAvatarIsOn", product.id); //I added it as product.id for this example, you will need to decide how you will do it. 
        Application.LoadLevel("Scene/Room3");
    }

    public void BuyFailed(UnityEngine.Purchasing.Product product, UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchaseFailureReason fa)
    {
        Debug.Log("PURCHASE FAILED");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did add a message there `//I added it as product.id for this example, you will need to decide how you will do it.` I don't know how you are handling it so used that as a placeholder, when you purchase it I assume you make a reference to the AvatarID somewhere? you need to use that.